# fullCalendar how to set the events programmatically

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having a problem setting the calendar event grammatically.

I have a page where the user can select the client to display the event for using a drop down.  I request the events via an Ajax call.  And this all looks good.  But I'm having a problem setting the events in fullCalendar.

This is my code to set the events:

```
success: function(resp){
    var r = resp.output;
    console.dir(r);
    jQuery('#student').html(r.studentname);
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' );  // <= This works
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'events', r.events ); // <= This doesn't
}
```

This is a dump of the ajax response:

```
events       "[{
             id: 1,
             title: 'Acupuncture',
             start: new Date(2013, 5, 29, 10, 00),
             end: new Date(2013, 5, 29, 10, 30),
             allDay: false
             }
             ,
             {
             id: 2,
             title: 'Acupuncture',
             start: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 10, 00),
             end: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 10, 30),
             allDay: false
             }
             ,
             {
             id: 3,
             title: 'Chiropractor',
             start: new Date(2013, 6, 31, 11, 00),
             end: new Date(2013, 6, 31, 11, 15),
             allDay: false
             }
             ]
             "
id          "1"
studentname "Tarah Yates"
```

I couldn't find any examples on how to do this so I'm not sure if I am doing it right.

I just noticed the quotes around the event list, maybe that's the problem?

If that's not the problem, does anybody have any thoughts on why it's not working?

Comment: try to call rerenderEvents method after adding the events

Answer (score 0):

gwardell that response needs to be iterated so you can fetch the elements of the array. But i would change the type of response to JSON like this:

```
[{
   "id": "1",
   "title": "Acupuncture",
   "start": "29-05-2013 10:00", //adapted this date format is accepted by fullcalendar
   "end": "29-05-2013 10:30",  
   "allDay": false  //You dont need to adapt this it was a mistake of me. Leave it be.
},etc, etc, etc]
```

**Notice that there can only be simple JSON, you can't have a response with complex JSON with sub-arrays.**

PS. - Go and study a bit of JSON format on the NET and you will figure it out i'm sure.

Not sure about that line, but what you wanna do will only create the event in that view while your are there, when you switch to other view will disapear. What you want to do is to save to a Database or whatever you use to store data to store the events. Then they will be persistent and when you **refetchevents** the event will apear...so jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'events', 'refetchevents' );

**How to pass the ID in ajax call assuming you are doing this with JSON and Jquery Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',                           
                        url: _url,                          
                        data: {'id': 9999, //Just pass like this or you can set like a function 'id':getMyID(),                                                             
                                'title':name,
                                'start':start,
                                'end':end,
                                'allDay': allDay,
                                'editable': true, 
                                },                                      
                        success: function(data) {           
                            //TODO Do stuff

                        }
                    });
```

**or if you have an array of eventsources**

```
 var othersources = {       
        ausencias: {               
        url: _url,
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            'id':getMyId(), // 'id':myidvalue                                                   
                         'func':func,
                      'year':y                                      
             },
        cache: false,              
        color: '#C1272D',
        textColor: 'white'                             
        }}
```

Comment: Let me know if you need further explanation...

Live long and prosper

Comment: I don't know how to adapt those three line to JSON. BTW, they are identical to the sample provided with the download which was hard coded into the  demo/test page.

Comment: When you say "iterated", do you mean I can only load one event at a time?

Is this line correct for loading the event?

    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'events', r.events );

Comment: Is this line the correct way of replacing the events?
`code`
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'events', r.events );

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I didn't know it took a string format. I was following his example where he creates a date object and was going through all sorts of hoop to get it from a MySql datetime format to that.  I'm going to try recreating the whole calender and see if that works.  I think you are right that I need to do an AJAX call to fetch each day. But I have to have something working by tonight so I'll do that bit later.

Comment: You dont need to fetch one by one, you can fetch one "JSON" array that contains several event JSON objects...

Comment: I tried several things to add an array to the calendar and none worked.  I don't think its possible to problematically add events to the calendar.  At least not the way I'm trying.  I even tried rebuilding the whole calendar and that didn't work.

The way the seems most likely to work now is to have the calender do an AJAX call to pull the events from a web service and do a refresh to trigger the calendar to do that.

Do you see any problem with that approach?

Comment: Nope and thats the correct way to do things, but i see now what were you trying to do, you wanna to do something without calling a web service, for performance issues right?

Comment: Yes, partially.  The user changes a drop down on the page that calls for a different calendar.  I have to update some stuff on the page so why not get the calendar in the same request.  The calendars will be sparsely populated so should be light weight.

Comment: I see, i would probably divide the problem into pieces, first try when you press the dropdown change the event sources of the calendar, and not all the calendar...i can show you how to achieve that.

Comment: Ok, I've been working on another part of the project.  I'm going to the AJAX thing to fetch the events.  I haven't looked but I'm hoping there is a way to pass an ID, corresponding to the drop down choice, for what events to fetch.  If you have some pointers on how to set that up that would help.  I was supposed to have the whole project done today but it looks like that won't happen.  Thanks.

Comment: You want to pass an id in ajax headers? Simple ;) check my edit.